# Visual Studio 2012 - where has ASPX design and split view gone?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

Just started a new web forms project in Visual Studio 2012.

Opened my aspx page in 2012 and there is no Split or Design View?

I am using the RTM version.

Have they honestly taken this out? If not, where can I find them?

Comment: The designer offers a simple UI to add a data source + plus its also useful for editing controls on the page

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Follow theses steps

> Go to  Tools --> Select Options
>
> Tick the box at the bottom of this dialog: Show all settings.
>
> Select HTML Designer --> Enable HTML designer

Answer (score 0):

For those using Visual Studio 2015:

1. In **Solution Explorer**, right-click on the file you wish to open.
2. Choose **Open With** from the pop-up menu.
3. In the **Open With** dialog box, choose **HTML (Web Forms) Editor**, optionally click the **Set as Default** button, and click the **OK** button.

Apparently the **HTML (Web Forms) Editor** has Design, Split, and Source tabs but the **HTML Editor** does not. **HTML Editor** seems to be the default editor for Razor and plain HTML files.

Answer (score 0):

For VS 2017/2019 Go to Tools -> Settings -> Web Forms Designer and click on the "Enable Web Forms designer" option