# design view of visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I just installed Visual Studio 2012 and I am writing a C# program. However I can't see ho to switch to design view. In Visual Studio 2012 I seem to recall that there were tabs beside the main text area that let you select between code, design or split views?  By the way when I was installing VS2012 I select web development as my 'main language' so I don't know if that might have something to do with the missing design view?

Comment: If you've selected a project type that supports design view, please make sure you're trying to see the design tab when an markup file(.*aspx, *.ascx, etc.) is opened and not a code behind file(.cs, etc) An example: [image](http://www.webprodutos.com/mysql612/users%20guide/images/connector-net-visual-studio-entity-framework-tutorial-linq-1.png)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2012 - where has ASPX design and split view gone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178359/visual-studio-2012-where-has-aspx-design-and-split-view-gone)